# Little help with XLinq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this XML:

```
<Test>
    <element>toto</element>
    <element>tata</element>
</Test>
```

How I can get the nodes "element"?. I see on the web I can get them with:

```
var elements = from element in xmlDoc.Descendants("element")
               select element;
```

But "elements" is empty!

**EDIT 1:** I'm loading the XDocument with this exact XML:

```
<Test xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
    <element>toto</element>
    <element>tata</element>
</Test>
```

Comment: There is never a reason to write `from x in y select x`.

Comment: @SLaks: it's true, but here is for the test and to explain to you my problem! Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok well there's your problem, your names have to be qualified with the appropriate XML namespace.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
var elements = xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "element");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a problem with how you are creating your `XDocument` object.  The following code works fine for me:

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
    <Test>
        <element>toto</element>
        <element>tata</element>
    </Test>");
var elements = doc.Descendants("element");
//prints "2"
Console.WriteLine(elements.Count());
```

Comment: If you put in a language hint, you need to leave a blank line between the hint and the code.